# How does filepicker work in XUL::Gui?

Tags: perl, user-interface, xul

I'm starting to have a love/hate relationship with `XUL::Gui`.  I love it because the simple pieces are easy to use, but I hate it because its documentation is horrible.

In particular, I'm trying to use the `filepicker` function (listed under `gui functions` in [the main doc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XUL%3a%3aGui)), but whenever I try to use it--even by copying and pasting the code example in the documentation--the `filepicker` command seems to go unrecognized ("`Bareword 'filepicker' not allowed while 'strict subs' in use`").

My apologies if I'm missing anything obvious, but how is this function used in `XUL::Gui`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filepicker` is not exported by default, it is part of the `:widgets` export tag.

You can either use `use XUL::Gui ':all';` to get everything, or use `use XUL::Gui qw(:default filepicker);` to get the default set of imports and the filepicker.

Take a look at the [EXPORT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XUL%3a%3aGui#EXPORT) heading for more details.

Sorry the documentation is horrible, its a work in progress :)

Comment: Cool, okay the syntax works, but as soon as I click the button corresponding to `Button(id=>'filebtn',label=>'...',oncommand=>sub{$file= filepicker;})`, a new window starts to open and then the application shuts down.  I've added `localhost` to Firefox's trusted websites.  Is that what it means to have the gui "running in 'trusted' mode", or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: trusted mode is when the gui starts from XULRunner template files, and the javascript is subsequently running with chrome privileges (required for the filepicker).  If XUL::Gui detects that your system is capable of trusted mode, it tries to enable it by default.  You can increase the debug verbosity `display debug => 1, ...` and see if trusted mode is failing.  The current version of XUL::Gui only supports trusted mode with Firefox 3 or XULRunner.  They changed some things in Firefox 4 related to remote XUL, and I have not had time to get trusted mode working again.

Comment: Okay, so how do I enable trusted mode?  The server is running Firefox 3.